# Override pushViewController to show default UIViewController each time

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` that acts like a loader (or Activity Indicator if you will).

I want to override `pushViewController` to show the loader view controller each time before pushing the new `UIViewController`. When it's done it should push the new `UIViewController`.

I **DONT** want to display `UIActivityIndicator`.

What is the best possible way to do so?

Comment: So your actual requirement is not very clear. Do you want to override all the places you call `pushViewController` or do you want to present some view controller before navigating to another view controller?

Comment: I want to show a view controller every time before I push to another UIViewController